# Unable to create user in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

I have a 5 node cassandra cluster. On one of the node I am trying to create a user through cqlsh but it fails with below error.

Kindly help

```
cassandra@cqlsh> CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS cloud WITH PASSWORD 'scape' SUPERUSER; 

ServerError: <ErrorMessage code=0000 [Server error] message="java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE">
```

**Cassandra Version : 2.1.8**

Comment: These following links may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048278/cassandra-error-cannot-achieve-consistency-level-local-one-during-user-creati and https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureConfigNativeAuth.html

Comment: What is the RF for your system_auth keyspace?

Comment: @Aaron RF=1 for system_auth

Comment: Typically you'll want to make sure your RF on system_auth to be between 3 and # of nodes.